# How to disable paragraph text selection on ios with ionic framework

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework

I have a web app created with ionic framework.
I have to select text on ios safari and do some action on that selected text.

Problem: When I want to select a WORD (by holding tap on ios) it selects the whole paragraph. Depending on the font **size** and paragraph **length**, it

- sometimes select word,
- sometimes select whole paragraph and allow modifying (decreasing) the selection to word
- sometimes select whole paragraph and disallow modifying (decreasing). (Can not select what I want)

Here is a video demonstrating my problem: http://screencast.com/t/ZsRhyk1Gjzy

Question: How can I disable paragraph selection and force word selection on ios safari? There should be a way for conducting text selection behaviour. Something like a css or html trick.